# How Do I implement a Set as an abstract data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I have to implement a set as an abstract data type in Haskell. The task is the following:

A set models a set of elements. It is valid that a set is either the empty set or recursively consists of one element and the rest of the set.
The functions isEmpty, contains, add, remove are to be defined.

- The function isEmpty checks if a set is empty.
- contains takes a set and an element and indicates whether the set contains the element.
- add takes a set and an element and adds the element to the set if it is not already in the set. is not already contained in the set
- The remove function takes a set and an element and removes the element from the set, if the element is already in the set. If the element is not part of the set, the the function returns an error.

im struggling with the recursive part of the task, I have no idea. And how do I implement the "contains" specifically?

```
module Set (Set(EmptySet, MkSet), isEmpty, contains, add, remove)
    where
        
data Set a = EmptySet | MkSet a (Set a)
    deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Ord, Read)

isEmpty :: Set a -> Bool
isEmpty EmptySet = True
isEmpty (MkSet a as) = False

contains :: Set a -> a -> Bool
contains EmptySet = error "no element in set."
contains (MkSet a as) a = True
contains (MkSet a as) b = False

add :: a -> Set a -> Set a
add a as = (MkSet a as)

remove :: Set a -> Set a
remove EmptySet = error "No remove operation on empty set allowed."
remove (MkSet a as) = as
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8kSj.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: An abstract data type is one with an interface but no implementation. You are defining a concrete data type.

Comment: If you are just deriving Eq rather than defining it, it is highly doubtful whether your implementation will ensure that set [1,2] is seen as equal to set [2,1]. Is this what you want ?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the abbreviation "ADT" can mean "abstract data type" but it can *also* mean "algebraic data type" (which is what is created with the `data` keyword in Haskell). This can sometimes cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `contains (MkSet a as) a` which uses the pattern variable `a` twice is called a nonlinear pattern in the literature. Nonlinear patterns are not allowed in Haskell. Instead you must check equality explicitly like this:

```
contains (MkSet a as) b
  | a == b = ...
  | otherwise = ...
```

This also requires adding `contains :: Eq a => Set a -> a -> Bool` in the type signature.

Note that the fact that `a` and `b` are different variables doesn't necessarily mean that they must be assigned different values when matching.

Secondly, your case `contains (MkSet a as) b = False` doesn't take into account that the element might be contained in `as` (hint: use recursion).

And thirdly, it's not an error to ask if an element is in an empty set (thanks chepner). It should just return `False` in that case.

Comment: `contains :: Eq a => Set a -> a -> Bool
contains a EmptySet = False
contains (MkSet a as) b
    | a == b = False
    | otherwise = True`

Is this the right approach? I have no clue

Comment: @KristianDodig note the order of the arguments, it should be `contains EmptySet a = ...`. Also if `a == b` then you have found a match so you should return ...? And you are still lacking the recursion in the case that the element is not present on the "outer level" of the set.

Comment: `contains :: Eq a => Set a -> a -> Bool
contains EmptySet a = False
contains (MkSet a as) b
    | a == b = True
    | otherwise = False` 
I dont have any idea on how to implement a recursion into this problem. Do I have to make a loop which proves every element in my set? But how would I combine the old set a with as?

Comment: If `a == b` is false, there's still a chance that `as` contains `b`, right? How do you  check if some value `b` is in a set `as`?

Comment: `as == b`? Maybe a case with checking all elements in as?

Comment: `contains 3 (MkSet 1 (MkSet 3 EmptySet))` should return true if `3` is in the set. Think about what values `a` and `as` are bound to. Since `1 /= 3`, maybe `contains 3 (MkSet 3 EmptySet)` would return `True`....

Comment: Maybe an elem checking if b is in as?

Comment: You are currently writing a function that checks if a value is an element of the set. Use that same function: that's all recursion is. (Basically, `contains` *is* `elem`, but with type `Eq a => Set a -> a -> Bool` instead of `Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`.)

Comment: (`elem` takes its arguments in the order it does so that it can be used as an infix "operator": `elem 3 [1,2,3]` is the same as ``3 `elem` [1,2,3]``. `contains` just takes its arguments in the other order, and works on sets instead of lists.)

Comment: `contains :: Eq a => Set a -> a -> Bool
contains EmptySet a = False
contains (MkSet a as) b
    | a == b = True
    | otherwise = contains as b = True `

still errors.. This is like my first programm, sorry

Comment: @KristianDodig there's only one small mistake which is that you are using `=` to check for equality on that last line, but in Haskell checking for equality can only be done with `==`. Also note that you never need to write `x == True`, because that is always the same as just writing `x`.